# Calling my Next JS /api endpoint from getStaticProps will not set a cookie

Tags: node.js, cookies, next.js

I am getting data from a remote API. The remote API uses a JS Web Token to allow access. In my getStaticProps function, I call my local /api endpoint and in that endpoint I check to see if there is a cookie already set, containing the last good token. If not, I call the remote API for a fresh token and set a new cookie with that token.

This is to save the remote API being called every time I need to get data from that server. All of my tests worked perfectly (when I directly called the /api endpoint using my browser), with my /api endpoint getting the remote token only when needed. However, when I wired the solution into my app and placed the local /api call in getStaticProps, the /api stopped setting the cookie altogether and kept calling the remote API for the token. I have stripped out my code to create a test which gives the same behaviour. Sample below:

## /cookietest.js

```
function cookietest({tokenObj}) {

    const pageTitle = 'cookie test'

    return (
        <div>
            <Head>
                <title>Cookie tester</title>
            </Head>
            <Header pageTitle={pageTitle} />
            <p>{tokenObj.token}</p>
            <p>{tokenObj.message}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {

    async function getToken() {
        let tokenObject
        await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/otherpath/token')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            tokenObject = data
        })
        return tokenObject
    }

    const tokenObj = await getToken()

    return {
        props: {
            tokenObj: tokenObj
        }
    }

}

export default cookietest
```

## /otherpath/token/index.js

```
import cookie from 'cookie'

export default async (req, res) => {

  res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie.serialize("token", 'adffdafadf', {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    maxAge: 60 * 60,
    sameSite: "strict",
    path: "/"
  }))

  const returnObject = {
    token: 'kdkdkkdkdk',
    message: 'Success - from local test'
  }
  
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.json(returnObject)

}
```

So, this returns my manual token perfectly and it gets displayed on the 'cookietest' page. But, the cookie never gets set. Can anyone tell me why this happens and give me a better method to make this work?

Comment: `getStaticProps` runs on the server at build time, it doesn't have access to request specific data like cookies. Make the request from the client-side instead (inside React component) if you want to set cookies.

Comment: Tks @juliomalves Not sure if that pattern would work. I need to get a list of items from the remote API initially, so that they show up in a page with a list component. That's why I'm using the getStaticProps function - to get the data in advance. If there's a different way to do this I'd be interested to know.

Comment: If the request to the API requires a specific token for authentication then you'll have to hardcode that token on the server-side if you want to fetch the data from `getStaticProps`. You can't use client-side cookies from there.

Comment: Alternatively, you can always use `getServerSideProps` instead, which gives you access to cookies through the `req` object.

Comment: Tried getServerSideProps with no joy either. The cookies are secure and set serverside. Can't hardcode the token because I need to update it every 24 hours. The Next JS app is essentially 'serverless' so there's no way to persist it locally, except with server side cookies (to prevent cross site script hacks) so that's why I need to use them. Bit of a quandary but I'm sure someone has a pattern for it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies may only be set in the interaction between the browser and the server. Your sample code is an interaction between two servers. The set cookie never gets to the browser.

To pass the cookie to the browser you'd need your cookietest.js to look something like:

```
import cookie from 'cookie'

function cookietest({tokenObj}) {

    const pageTitle = 'cookie test'

    return (
        <div>
            <Head>
                <title>Cookie tester</title>
            </Head>
            <Header pageTitle={pageTitle} />
            <p>{tokenObj.token}</p>
            <p>{tokenObj.message}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {

    async function getToken() {
        let cookieValue = null;
        const tokenObject = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/otherpath/token')
        .then(response =>{
            cookieValue = response.headers.get('set-cookie').split(',').reduce((a,c)=>{
                if(!a){
                    const nvp = (c.split(';')[0]).split('=');
                    if(nvp[0] == 'token') return nvp[1];
                }
                return a;

            }, null);
            return response.json();
        });

        return {
            tokenObject,
            cookieValue
        };
            
    }

    const {tokenObj, cookieValue} = await getToken();
    ctx.res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie.serialize("token", cookieValue, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        maxAge: 60 * 60,
        sameSite: "strict",
        path: "/"
    }));

    return {
        props: {
            tokenObj: tokenObj
        }
    }

}
export default cookietest
```

Comment: Thanks @bknights. I need a second to absorb this... In my final use case I will need to check if the token cookie has been set, if it has then use the cookie's token value, otherwise reach out to the API to get a fresh one from a remote server. If I understand your code correctly, it seems that I can include npm cookies and check for the existence of the cookie first in the getServerSideProps function? Would that sound about right? p.s. thanks for the explanation of why it *wasn't* working. I understand that better now.

Comment: Yes. You can check the existence of the cookie in getServerSideProps and only generate the token if necessary.

Comment: great. Thanks bknights. Accepting this as the answer. A bit of refactoring to do and I should get it working with this information.